# "nc -lk 9999" shows no output for spark streaming in VM

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I followed https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html for spark streaming. I ran the program `network_wordcount.py` given in github. Started worker and master. Then on one terminal executed `nc -lk 9999` and on another `./network_wordcount.py localhost 9999`.
Output of `nc -lk 9999` is just `blank`. Shows nothing.

Output of `./spark-submit network_wordcount.py localhost 9999` shows only `INFO:` which seems never ending:

I'm not getting the output the document shows. No data is being streamed. Is there something I'm missing out for streaming to happen?

Answer (score 1):

> Output of nc -lk 9999 is just blank. Shows nothing.

It will be blank and you have to type words on that terminal so they can be streamed.